# Android - RecyclerView drag using ItemTouchHelper.Callback

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager, itemtouchhelper

I'm currently working on an small Android module and I'm facing a problem which maybe someone can solve. I need to **create a calendar and allow the user to select a date range by 1) clicking on a start date (this will create a 2 days range by default) and then 2) touching one range border and dragging it to increase or decrease that range**.

Currently I've created all the calendar days cells using a **RecyclerView with a GridLayoutManager** which has a lot of rows (all the weeks) with 7 items per row (the days). Then **I've used the RecyclerView ItemTouchHelper** (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.html) **and ItemTouchHelper.Callback** (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.Callback.html) **to complete the drag&drop functionality**. My approach was to use the drag&drop detection provided by those helpers (take a look at https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-b9456d2b1aaf#.ib8r012gc) modifying it to avoid moving one item and only detecting the touch+drag+drop gesture I wanted. I've correctly completed the functionality by removing the default drag animation (overriding ItemTouchHelper onDraw/onDrawOver) and using the ItemTouchHelper.Callback callbacks to manage the drag movement (without swapping the adapter items, because I need them always at the same position). All works fine but **I'm now facing a problem because the drag detection is not working as expected**. I'll try to explain it: **if I start the drag movement in the center of a given cell, and I move to the cell to its left, the drag movement isn't triggered until I've reached the center** (the same position at where I've started the drag movement) of the left cell. This is a problem because I need to detect a drag as soon as I reach another cell (if the finger is inside the new cell bounds, the drag should be triggered). Another example is: if I start the drag movement in the leftmost side of a cell, the drag won't be triggered until I reach the leftmost side of another cell.

Now **I'm trying to play a bit with the ItemTouchHelper.Callback.chooseDropTarget method** to manually select the drop target as soon as the fingers enters a new cell but I'm not able to get it work. I think (but I cannot ensure it) that is something strange with the received x,y coordinates.

I know that some code example would be very helpful but I cannot paste it because it belongs to a private and protected repository :(

**Any help that anyone could provide to me will be really appreciated**. And, of course, I'll try to be pending of this topic to provide all the info I can. I will also take into account **new different approaches and suggestions to get the "touch+move+up" movement** which I need to move ranges borders :)

Many thanks in advance to all the Stack Overflow community!

Comment: Check out this: https://medium.com/@ipaulpro/drag-and-swipe-with-recyclerview-6a6f0c422efd#.t9hfxpph4

Comment: Thank you @XxGoliathusxX. I've already checked your link but I still have the same problem ;)  I had followed that link and some other ones when I started developing this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more research, I found the solution to my problem. I'll post it so if someone faces the same issue, he can find some help here :)

My problem was that I was using the `curX` and `curY` parameters returned by `ItemTouchHelper.Callback.chooseDropTarget` (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/helper/ItemTouchHelper.Callback.html#chooseDropTarget(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder,%20java.util.List%3Candroid.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.ViewHolder%3E,%20int,%20int)) as if they were the current finger coordinates while dragging, but they are the coordinates of the top leftmost coordinate of the dragged view after applying any translation. Now I feel a bit stupid. I should have read the documentation better :|

As I didn't need that top leftmost coordinate but the finger position, my solution was to use a touch listener attached to the source view so I could detect the initial touch x,y coordinates (relative to that view) using the `touchSrcX = MotionEvent.getX()` and `touchSrcY = MotionEvent.getY()` methods and then I applied a point translation before selecting a target in the `chooseDropTarget` callback. I mean, something like:

`curX += touchSrcX
curY += touchSrcY`

If someone needs more details or a better explanation, please, contact me and I'll be pleased to help! :)

Comment: How about using ItemTouchHelper.Callback.onChildDraw dX dY together with the original x and y coordinates of the ViewHolder?